# Rails with ajax not working in another records

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

In my controller:

```
def change
@commit=Commit.find(params[:id])
@user=@commit.user
@user.name=params[:name]
@user.save
respond_to do |format|
  format.html { redirect_to 'commits' }
  format.js
end
end
```

In my model:

```
class Commit < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

In my view:

```
<table width="1600" bordercolor=#cccccc border=1 frame=hsides rules=rows>
  <% @commits.each do |commit| user=commit.user %>
 <tr> 
   <td valign="top" width="60"><%= commit.user.id %></td>
   <td valign="top" width="130"><%=render partial: 'name_form', :locals => {:commit =>commit} %></td>
   <td valign="top" width="150"><%= commit.user.email %></td>      
   <td valign="top" width="150"><%= commit.hash_commit %></td>
   <td valign="top" width="90"><%= commit.date_commit %></td>
   <td valign="top" width="630"><%=raw commit.description %></td>
</tr>
```

And partial:

```
<%= form_tag change_path, method: :post, :remote => true do |f| %>
 <%= text_field_tag :name, commit.user.name, :onkeyup => "this.form.sub.click()" %>
 <%= hidden_field_tag :id , commit.id %>
<% end %>
```

And js file is:

```
$("#name_form").html("<%= text_field_tag :name, commit.user.name, :onkeyup => "this.form.sub.click()" %>");
```

When I change name of user in commit it is change in date base without page refresh. But I have a page refresh to change user names of another commits. What is wrong?

Comment: I'm sorry, it's kind of unclear to me, are you asking why you need to refresh the page in order for database changes to show up in your browser?

Comment: You are right. That is a problem.

Comment: Well... you're submitting the form remotely, but you're never using javascript to update the content of the page... so of course you're going to have to refresh....

Comment: And how to use javascript to update the content of the page? Help me.

Comment: Honestly, writing a bunch of code for you is something outside the scope of something like Stackoverflow. I would say read up on ajax requests, and take a look at some jquery documentation, here's a start: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: It can not help solve a problem. It is a good idea to read a lot of books. But where is mistake?

Comment: Your mistake is that you don't understand what Ajax calls are actually doing. They're sending a request off to the remote server asynchronously from javascript. They tell you nothing about the DOM content on the page. What you need to do is fire off an ajax request and then do some sort of re-rendering DOM manipulation after the ajax request has succeeded.

Comment: The problem that I need Ajax to manipulate the field from where Ajax request. It is the same field